# Изменение параметра "Shell" в редакторе групповой политики посредствам vbs скрипта

Tags: windows

Нужна ваша помощь. Так как я не совсем понимаю vbs, то написать это по гайдам гугла я не смог. Вот что мне нужно:

Скрипт VBS который будет редактировать значения реестра Shell *(Путь указан ниже)*, не удаляя а добавляя к строке Explorer.exe допустим значение C:\Folder\1.exe.

**Путь до скрипта** - **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon** - **Параметр Shell**

Comment: Может посложнее троян написать?

Comment: На шарпе хотя бы?

Comment: Может лучше в сторону пошика смотреть?